# Kubernetes - set env var using the value of one of the auto generated service env vars

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Kubernetes automatically generates several environment variables for you, like `SERVICE1_SERVICE_HOST` and `SERVICE1_SERVICE_PORT`. I would like to use the value of these variables to set my own variables in the deployment.yml, like below:

```
env:
- name: MY_NEW_VAR
  value: ${SERVICE1_SERVICE_HOST}
```

For some reason Kubernetes isn't able to resolve this. When I go inside the container it turns out it has been assigned as a literal string, giving me `MY_NEW_VAR = ${SERVICE1_SERVICE_HOST}.`

Is there a way to assign the value of `${SERVICE1_SERVICE_HOST}` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is `$(SERVICE1_SERVICE_HOST)`, as one can see in [the fine manual](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/#using-environment-variables-inside-of-your-config)